# BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\registeration::register() error

Tags: php, laravel

hello friends I am trying to insert the data in database while using Laravel. I am getting the error BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\registeration::register() while register.blade.php is my view and registeration is the name of my table. The controller name is RegisterationContoller and its code is given.

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\registeration;

class RegisterationController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // register view
        return view('register');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        registeration::register(Request::all());
        //
        return 'insert';
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

The code of web.php is given and it works correctly, before I have checked as a test. please help me any body.

the Code of My model registeration.php is given

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class registeration extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = ['sname','fname','gyear','phone','email','paddress','prog','job','org','position'];
}
```

The code of my view is give below which is actually register.blade.php

```
    @extends('master')

@section('content')
<div class="container"><br>
        <h1 class="text-success text-center">Student Registration Form</h1><br>
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 m-auto d-block">
            <form action="store" method="post" onsubmit="return validation()">

                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Student Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="sname" id="sname" class="form-control">
                    <span id="studenterror" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Father Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="form-control">
                    <span id="fnameerror" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Graduation Year: </label>
                    <input type="date" name="gyear" id="gyear" class="form-control">
                    <span id="gyearerror" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Phone: </label>
                    <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control">
                    <span id="phoneerror" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email: </label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control">
                    <span id="emailerror" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Postal Address: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="paddress" id="paddress" class="form-control">
                    <span id="addresserror" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Program: </label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="program">
                        <option  value="Nill">Select Program</option>
                        <option  value="msc">MSc</option>
                        <option  value="bs">BS</option>
                        <option  value="mphil">MPhil</option>
                        <option  value="phd">PHD</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label>Job</label><br>
                    <div class="form-control radio-inline">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="job" value="yes" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#org">Yes</label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="job" value="no" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#">No      </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>


  <div id="org" class="collapse">
    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Organization: </label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="org">
                        <option  value="Nill">Select Organization</option>
                        <option value="Higher_Education">Higher Education</option>
                        <option  value="Software_House">Software House</option>
                        <option  value="Hardware_industry">Hardware Industry</option>
                        <option  value="other">Other</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                <label>Position</label>
                <input type="text" name="position" class="form-control" id="position">

                </div>
  </div><br>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-lg col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 m-auto d-block">
  </div>


            </form>

        </div>
    </div>

    </script>
<br>
<a href="{{url('/plearning')}}" class="btn btn-primary">Back to Home</a>
@endsection

And the code of web.php is given below.
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/plearning','HomeController@index');

//for create
Route::get('create','testing@index');
Route::post('save','testing@store');


//For new Registration form
Route::get('register','RegisterationController@index');
Route::post('store','RegisterationController@store');
```

Now where is the problem I dont know more

Comment: see there is the error. your `registeration` model doesn't have a function called `register()`

Comment: So how it can be correct?

Comment: `registeration::create($reqquest->all());`